# Error encountered with QuillEditor.basic() when readOnly is set to false in flutter_quill package

Tags: flutter, dart, quill, flutter-packages

I am currently using the flutter_quill package in my Flutter project and I have encountered an issue with the QuillEditor.basic() widget. Here is my current configuration:

```dart
QuillEditor.basic(
  controller: _controller,
  readOnly: false,
)
```

[image: current code screenshot]

When I set `readOnly` to false, I am encountering an error with the message int assertionStart, int assertionEnd, Object? message) from the errors_patch.dart file. However, if I set `readOnly` to true, I don't encounter any errors.

I have checked the documentation and reviewed my implementation, but I couldn't find a solution to this issue. I would greatly appreciate it if someone could provide guidance on how to resolve this error when `readOnly` is set to false.

[image: warning preview]

Comment: the error you showed us in the dart-vm is not of much help but it it shows that some assertion has not been true. In your debug view, have a look at the call stack to find out which assertion has not been met / triggered the error